# Is standard deviation sensitive to arithmetic mean?

Tags: statistics

I have two sets of data, A and B, their arithmetic means are $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$, and standard deviations are $\sigma_a$, $\sigma_b$, if A and B has the same sample size, and  $\sigma_a < \sigma_b$, can I say that the data in A is more stable than those in B, even if $\bar{B} > \bar{A}$?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "stable".

Comment: And are you interested in the actual populations from which you derived the means and deviations, or just about the data sets?

Comment: @Henry "stable" means the data is less spread, they are all not far from the arithmetic mean.

Comment: That would suggest $\{1,5,7\}$ are more *stable* than $\{10000010,10000050,10000070\}$.  You could use standard deviation, or average absolute deviation, or range, or many similar measures.  If on the other hand you see the second set as more stable, you might want to look at coefficient of variation

Comment: @Henry The second definitely is more stable than the first one, thanks for pointing me to coefficient of variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessary.

Let A be a  set of 100 humans with mean weight 70 kg, and standard deviation 20 kg.

Let B be a  set of 100 elephants with mean weight $8000$ kg and standard deviation 40kg.

Clearly even with standard deviation doubled (for the same sample size)
elephants seem to be more homogeneous in weight.

Answer (score 0):

I would see it this way: if you have a large-enough sample-size for each, and the data is roughly-symmetric and the sample standard deviation is not too large, then you can consider $\sigma_a , \sigma_b $ to be valid measures of spread _from the underlying populations from which the data came. In this case, you may say that one population has less, or smaller spread than the other .Otherwise, if $\sigma_a, \sigma_b$ are "too large" , depending on the situation/context at hand, there may be better measures of spread of the data, like the interquartile range.