# How to measure the stability of datas

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

The background: I have a server handling $n$ kinds of requests, denoted by $k_1, ..., k_n$, at a certain time, many requests has been processed, the average time it takes to process $k_i$ is $t_i$, for $i \neq j$, $\left|t_i - t_j\right|$ can be very large, or very small.

The question: Is there a function, $f$, it takes a list of numbers, (in this specific case, the numbers are the time consumed by processing $k_i$), and yields a number, so that, for $j \in \{1,...n\}$, I get n numbers, $f_1, ..., f_n$, which allows me to know, by the magnitude of these numbers, among these $n$ kinds requests, which one is most unstable to process?

Comment: Not sure I understand: you have $n$ *types* of tasks, and all you get are the $t_i$'s, which are the $n$ *average* times to process each of the $n$ types? I.e., you don't have the individual times (one for each request, say for instance $m$ times for type $1$, if you had $m$ requests of type $1$ that you used to compute the average time $t_1$)?

Comment: No, I have all the raw data, to be specific, $k_i$ has been processed $a_i$ times, it takes $b_{ij}$ seconds to process $k_i$ at the $j$-th time, $1 \leq j \leq a_i$.

Comment: $f$ should be a function looks like this: $f(b_{i1}, ..., b_{ia_i}) = m$, where $m$ measures the variance of $(b_{i1}, ..., b_{ia_i})$.

Comment: Then you may for instance look at the [(empirical) variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sample_variance) of the time needed for type $i$ -- right now, the $t_i$'s give you the (empirical) mean, the variance will provide a bit more regarding how "spread out" these times are. Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance): "In probability theory and statistics, variance measures how far a set of numbers is spread out."

Comment: But it didn't allow me to compare the variance between $k_i$s, see [my other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1340995/is-standard-deviation-sensitive-to-arithmetic-mean/1341028#1341028) for details.

Comment: To compare things with difference magnitudes, you can renormalize them, e.g. by dividing the variance by the square of the mean (see [the coefficient of variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_variation)). This will have other issues, which may not be a problem with you (e.g., an average very close to $0$ will bias the results, as you divide by it).